# Wordpress Plugin Javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, jquery-ui-accordion

I purchased a [Wordpress accordion plugin](http://unlimited-addons.com/content-accordions-addons-for-wpbakery-page-builder/) that's an addon for the [WPBakery Page Builder](https://wpbakery.com/) and the support has been less than helpful. What I would like is to have users click on the title once to open a panel and click on the title again to close the panel. I have all the panels closed by default when the page loads.

You can see the accordion here: [Wordpress accordion plugin](http://unlimited-addons.com/content-accordions-addons-for-wpbakery-page-builder/), it's about the 10th one down:

this is the accordion [image: the accordion]

The javascript that is being provided is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.uc_material_accordion .uc_trigger-{{uc_id}}').click(function(){
        if( jQuery(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
        jQuery('.uc_material_accordion .uc_trigger-{{uc_id}}').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();
        }
        return false;
        });
    });
```

If anyone can help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They get the money and we should do support for free! :) you can do something like this:

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.uc_material_accordion .uc_trigger-{{uc_id}}').click(function(){
        if( jQuery(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();
        } else {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideUp();
        }
    return false;
    });
});
```

**P.S**: You want to make an accordion to act like tab widget. This line of code will make your widget accordion

```
jQuery('.uc_material_accordion .uc_trigger-{{uc_id}}').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
```

Comment: that worked perfectly, thanks a lot! Yeah it's a shame that they get the money but don't support it.

Comment: @DaveM I'm glad